# Firma facturae con certificado

Tags: java

No es una pregunta, sólo quiero compartir el código que me habría ayudado cuando intenté usar librerías de xades para firmar facturas con certificado pero hacienda las rechazaba.

Necesitaba poder firmar facturas con sus certificados como lo hace autofirma, probé con varias librerías pero ninguna daba resultados válidos ni pude encontrar respuestas que hicieran lo que necesitaba o lo dejaban sin responder, así que aquí os dejo el código que me ha funcionado que imita el resultado para las facturae 3.1

Ya va preparado para usar, los parámetros son las rutas de entrada, salida, certificado y la contraseña del certificado.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMDigestMethod;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.Init;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.signature.ObjectContainer;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.signature.XMLSignature;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.transforms.Transforms;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.XMLUtils;

/////

File entrada = new File(args[0]);
File salida = new File(args[1]);
String certificado = args[2];
String contraseña = args[3];
String urlpdf="http://www.facturae.es/politica_de_firma_formato_facturae/politica_de_firma_formato_facturae_v3_1.pdf";


DocumentBuilderFactory docfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docfac.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = docfac.newDocumentBuilder().parse(entrada);


Init.init();
XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(doc, null, XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256);
sig.setId("signature");
doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(sig.getElement());


KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(certificado), contraseña.toCharArray());
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(ks.aliases().nextElement());
sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
sig.addKeyInfo(cert.getPublicKey());
sig.getKeyInfo().setId("keyinfo");



Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_ENVELOPED_SIGNATURE);
sig.addDocument("", transforms, DOMDigestMethod.SHA512, "reference", null);

ObjectContainer obj = new ObjectContainer(doc);
sig.appendObject(obj);
    Element QualifyingProperties=doc.createElement("QualifyingProperties");
    QualifyingProperties.setAttribute("Id", "qualifyingproperties");
    QualifyingProperties.setIdAttribute("Id", true);
    obj.appendChild(QualifyingProperties);
        Element SignedProperties=doc.createElement("SignedProperties");
        SignedProperties.setAttribute("Id", "signedproperties");
        SignedProperties.setIdAttribute("Id", true);
        QualifyingProperties.appendChild(SignedProperties);
            
            Element SignedSignatureProperties=doc.createElement("SignedSignatureProperties");
            SignedProperties.appendChild(SignedSignatureProperties);
            
                Element SigningTime=doc.createElement("SigningTime");
                SigningTime.setTextContent(new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
                SignedSignatureProperties.appendChild(SigningTime);
                
                Element SigningCertificate=doc.createElement("SigningCertificate");
                SignedSignatureProperties.appendChild(SigningCertificate);
                    Element Cert=doc.createElement("Cert");
                    SigningCertificate.appendChild(Cert);
                        Element CertDigest=doc.createElement("CertDigest");
                        Cert.appendChild(CertDigest);
                            
                            Element DigestMethod=doc.createElement("DigestMethod");
                            DigestMethod.setAttribute("Algorithm", DOMDigestMethod.SHA512);
                            CertDigest.appendChild(DigestMethod);
                            
                            Element DigestValue=doc.createElement("DigestValue");
                            MessageDigest mg=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
                            mg.update(cert.getEncoded());
                            DigestValue.setTextContent(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(mg.digest()));
                            CertDigest.appendChild(DigestValue);
                        
                        Element IssuerSerial=doc.createElement("IssuerSerial");
                        Cert.appendChild(IssuerSerial);
                            
                            Element X509IssuerName=doc.createElement("X509IssuerName");
                            X509IssuerName.setTextContent(cert.getIssuerDN().getName());//deprecated -> cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName()
                            IssuerSerial.appendChild(X509IssuerName);
                            
                            Element X509SerialNumber=doc.createElement("X509SerialNumber");
                            X509SerialNumber.setTextContent(cert.getSerialNumber().toString());
                            IssuerSerial.appendChild(X509SerialNumber);
                            
                
                Element SignaturePolicyIdentifier=doc.createElement("SignaturePolicyIdentifier");
                SignedSignatureProperties.appendChild(SignaturePolicyIdentifier);
                    Element SignaturePolicyId=doc.createElement("SignaturePolicyId");
                    SignaturePolicyIdentifier.appendChild(SignaturePolicyId);
                        
                        Element SigPolicyId=doc.createElement("SigPolicyId");
                        SignaturePolicyId.appendChild(SigPolicyId);
                            
                            Element Identifier=doc.createElement("Identifier");
                            Identifier.setTextContent(urlpdf);
                            SigPolicyId.appendChild(Identifier);
                            
                            Element Description=doc.createElement("Description");
                            SigPolicyId.appendChild(Description);
                        
                        Element SigPolicyHash=doc.createElement("SigPolicyHash");
                        SignaturePolicyId.appendChild(SigPolicyHash);
                            
                            Element DigestMethod2=doc.createElement("DigestMethod");
                            DigestMethod2.setAttribute("Algorithm", DOMDigestMethod.SHA1);
                            SigPolicyHash.appendChild(DigestMethod2);
                            
                            Element DigestValue2=doc.createElement("DigestValue");
                            DigestValue2.setTextContent("Ohixl6upD6av8N7pEvDABhEL6hM=");//si cambia la urlpdf tendra que hacer digest
                            SigPolicyHash.appendChild(DigestValue2);
                            
                Element SignerRole=doc.createElement("SignerRole");
                SignedSignatureProperties.appendChild(SignerRole);
                    Element ClaimedRoles=doc.createElement("ClaimedRoles");
                    SignerRole.appendChild(ClaimedRoles);
                        Element ClaimedRole=doc.createElement("ClaimedRole");
                        ClaimedRole.setTextContent("emisor");
                        ClaimedRoles.appendChild(ClaimedRole);
                        
            Element SignedDataObjectProperties=doc.createElement("SignedDataObjectProperties");
            SignedProperties.appendChild(SignedDataObjectProperties);
                Element DataObjectFormat=doc.createElement("DataObjectFormat");
                DataObjectFormat.setAttribute("ObjectReference", "#reference");
                SignedDataObjectProperties.appendChild(DataObjectFormat);
                    
                    Element Description2=doc.createElement("Description");
                    DataObjectFormat.appendChild(Description2);
                    
                    Element ObjectIdentifier=doc.createElement("ObjectIdentifier");
                    DataObjectFormat.appendChild(ObjectIdentifier);
                        
                        Element Identifier2=doc.createElement("Identifier");
                        Identifier2.setAttribute("Qualifier", "OIDAsURN");
                        Identifier2.setTextContent("urn:oid:1.2.840.10003.5.109.10");
                        ObjectIdentifier.appendChild(Identifier2);
                        
                        Element Description3=doc.createElement("Description");
                        ObjectIdentifier.appendChild(Description3);
                        
                    Element MimeType=doc.createElement("MimeType");
                    MimeType.setTextContent("text/xml");
                    DataObjectFormat.appendChild(MimeType);
                    
                    Element Encoding=doc.createElement("Encoding");
                    DataObjectFormat.appendChild(Encoding);

sig.addDocument("#signedproperties", null, DOMDigestMethod.SHA512, null, "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties");
sig.addDocument("#keyinfo", null, DOMDigestMethod.SHA512);



sig.sign(ks.getKey(ks.aliases().nextElement(), contraseña.toCharArray()));
XMLUtils.outputDOM(doc, new FileOutputStream(salida), true);
```

Comment: "No es una pregunta": es bueno que quieras compartir conocimiento, pero recuerda que el formato de [es.so] es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Adapta tu _no-pregunta_ a tal formato. Lee [ask], [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: En acuerdo con el comentario anterior, normalmente se suele hacer una pregunta con el inconveniente que se nos ha presentado y posteriormente como respuesta escribimos la solución. De igual forma, gracias por compartir su solución, el trabajar con certificados y firmas suele complicarse a menudo